# UnityEvent Loses Its Custom Inspector When Serialized in a class as a property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

so i have an array of Serializable classes, each with its own array of Serializable classes each of those has a UnityEvent.

```
class a : ScriptableObject
{
    entry[] entries
}

[Serializable]
class entry
{
    option[] Options
}

[Serializable]
class option
{
    string name;
    UnityEvent action;
}
```

[the inspector of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7yxW.png)

as opposed to the normal inspector view

([example of normal inspector](https://forum.unity.com/proxy.php?image=http%3A%2F%2Fimage.noelshack.com%2Ffichiers%2F2015%2F40%2F1443875495-unityevent-problem.png&hash=0253ba890f4847d35fd3312b396991c7))

Comment: You can't serialize private fields by default, if you need serialize private or protected fields use `[SerializeField]` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize a UnityEvent. You need to create a custom class for this, like this:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1275147/can-you-force-unity-to-serialize-a-unityevent-in-t.html

Comment: also i had the problem where the class and file had a name miss match so it didnt work